# Join several times

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've a table with fields `id_osztaly`, `id_csoportositas` and `name` (and some other fields but there aren't important).

I want create a query with the follow result: I want combine the `name` fields. I can't explain so I show an example:
the datas in the table (`id_osztaly`, `id_csoportositas` and `name` order):

```
1,1,Group1A
1,1,Group1B
1,2,Group2A
1,2,Group2B
```

I want the follow combine from `name`:

```
Group1A-Group2A
Group1A-Group2B
Group1B-Group2A
Group1B-Group2B
```

(similar the permutation). I can do this with a `JOIN`, it's ok. But when I three different value of `id_csoportositas`:

```
1,1,Group1A
1,1,Group1B
1,2,Group2A
1,2,Group2B
1,3,Group3A
1,3,Group3B
1,3,Group3C
```

I want:

```
Group1A-Group2A-Group3A
Group1A-Group2A-Group3B
Group1A-Group2A-Group3C
Group1A-Group2B-Group3A
Group1A-Group2B-Group3B
Group1A-Group2B-Group3C
Group1B-Group2A-Group3A
Group1B-Group2A-Group3B
Group1B-Group2A-Group3C
Group1B-Group2B-Group3A
Group1B-Group2B-Group3B
Group1B-Group2B-Group3C
```

Yes, it's double join. But I don't know how many different `id_csoportositas` exist in table. First blick I think I need same number of `JOIN` as the number of different `id_csoportositas`.

Is there any trick in (my)sql to do this or should I do it in `PHP` with a `for`-cycle?

**EDIT** maybe I wasn't clear. I know how can I `JOIN` same table two times or three times. If I've two different `id_csoportositas` I need only one `JOIN`. If I've three different `id_csoportositas` I need two `JOIN` - I can do this too. But I don't know how many different `id_csoportositas` exist so I don't know how many `JOIN` will need. The number of `JOIN`s depends on number of different `id_csoportositas` and I don't know the number of `id_csoportositas` without a query.

And I want to group by `id_osztaly` and different `id_osztaly` has different `id_csoportositas`.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I dont know the solution yet, but i believe what you want is a self join + cross join. As i understand you have only one table, correct?

Comment: Try [http://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+double+join+same+table]

Comment: @devsundar Yes, I've only one table (only this is important in this case) and the field `name` want to combine.

Comment: @Yaroslav I know but my question wasn't `How to join same table multiple times?`. My question is how can I join different times same table. If I have one different `id_csoportositas`, I shouldn't JOIN. But if I've two different, I should JOIN one times. But if I've three different, I should JOIN two times. My question: 'Are any solution to JOIN different times?' Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Won't something like this work:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 1) a,
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 2) b,
    (SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 3) c
)
```

You just select like this and it would provide all possible variations of the joins :)

Comment: Oh. Well you can get the distinct `something` with a query and then use php to build the query using a loop. That is an easy solution.

Comment: Hm, it seems a very good idea! I've a table `csoportositas` which stores the possible `id_csoportositas`. I can query this number and I know how many times should use the table.

Comment: I've done it similar but very-very difficult - it works. Thanks for the good start point.